# Android, App Crashing, ListView Listeners

Tags: android, android-listview

I need help figuring out what is wrong in this code, i've searched how to implement the ListView OnItemClickListeners, but i can't get them to work.

The applications runs fine WITHOUT the method that sets the OnItemClickListeners, when i set them up, the application crash.

The purpose of this activity is to load the list with the clients that correspond with the spinner, (the spinner contains different cities), and then whenever an item is clicked, start a different activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinner2;
    private Button sync;
    private static String selectedOption = "";
    private ListView listview;
    private static ArrayList<String> values;
    private static Client[] clientArray;

    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sync = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSync);

        //Client list
        clientArray = new Client[5];

        //Populate the client list
        clientArray[0] = new Client("Roberto Herrero", "Resistencia", "Calle Falsa 123", 10.0f);
        clientArray[1] = new Client("Carlos Stigeslts", "Resistencia", "Calle Falsa 123", 10.0f);
        clientArray[2] = new Client("Pedro Zaragoza", "Resistencia", "Calle Falsa 123", 10.0f);
        clientArray[3] = new Client("Pablo Pedroso", "Charata", "Calle Falsa 123", 10.0f);
        clientArray[4] = new Client("Juan Jose Falalalala", "Resistencia", "Calle Falsa 123", 10.0f);

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        int count = 0;

        if(clientArray != null && clientArray.length != 0) {
            String local = clientArray[0].getLocality();
            list.add(local);
            for(int i = 0; i < clientArray.length; i++) {
                if(!local.equals(clientArray[i].getLocality())) {
                    if(!list.contains(clientArray[i].getLocality())) {
                        list.add(clientArray[i].getLocality());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        addSpinnerListener();
        addButtonListeners();

        //THIS IS CAUSING THE APP TO CRASH, WITHOUT THIS METHOD CALL, THE APPS RUNS FINE
        setListviewListeners();

    }

    public void setListviewListeners() {
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CLIENTVIEW");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void addSpinnerListener() {
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                String selected= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                selectedOption = selected;

                //List Values
                values = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(int i = 0; i < clientArray.length; i++) {

                    if(clientArray[i].getLocality().equalsIgnoreCase(selectedOption)) {
                        values.add(clientArray[i].getName() + "\n" + clientArray[i].getAddress());
                    }
                }

                //Declare, Define and find the ListView
                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

                ArrayList<String> vlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
                    vlist.add(values.get(i));
                }

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, vlist);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void addButtonListeners() {
        sync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("REPORT");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the xml

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSync"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SINCRONIZAR" />

    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/listview"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sistel.listview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sistel.listview.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.sistel.listview.ClientView"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CLIENTVIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

this is activity that i want to start

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="80"
                    android:text="Nombre"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_column="0"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="15"
                    android:text="Saldo"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_column="1"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:text="Cascos"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_column="2"/>
        </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:text="Saldo Anterior"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:text="SaldoA"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="CascosA"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_column="2"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:text="Retiros"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:text="SaldoA"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="2"
                android:id="@+id/editText"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:text="Entrega"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:text="Entrega"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="2"
                android:id="@+id/editText"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:text="Pagos"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="2"
                android:id="@+id/editText"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_column="1"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:text="Pagos"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:text="SaldoAc"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:text="CascosAc"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_column="1"/>
    </TableRow>
```

this is the JAVA of the activity i want to start

```
public class ClientView extends Activity {

    private Button update;
    private Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.client);

        initComponets();
        buttonListener();

    }

    public void initComponets() {
        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUpdate);
    }

    public void buttonListener() {
        update.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("REPORT");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("DUMMY PROCEDURE");
                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: If your app is crashing, please include the LogCat stack trace, as it always has the exact problematic line for you.

Comment: The crash happens when you click on a list item? Or, even before you have a chance to.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it appears to me that you never initialize `listview`. You declare it here

```
private ListView listview;
```

but it doesn't seem as though you initialize it, at least not before you try to set the `listener` on it. If this isn't your problem then please post the logcat so we can see exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Gabriel Matusevich does this. Just not in the right manner, in my opinion. Look at `addSpinnerListener()`, which is called before `setListviewListeners()`.

Comment: OMgg, that was it, yes,, the list was being initialized inside a methor but not on the onCreate,... problem is fixed

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich You may accept as the correct answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer if it worked for you